# How can I tell which alternative is used in PoE?

Tags: reverse-engineering, poe

I need to disable the power over ethernet being **output** by a device to prevent any damage to routers and switches. After looking more into how PoE works, there appears to be two *[alternatives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_over_Ethernet)* to how the power is sent over the wire.

Alternative A - Uses *phantom power*. This method involves sending power alongside the data signals since they are at such different frequencies.

Alternative B - Uses the unused wires of a 10/100 cable to send power.

I'm not certain as to whether the device is 10/100 or if it supports gigabit connections. If there is a way to discover the gigabit capabilities that would tell me that it cannot be alternative B. I don't have many details on the hardware, as it's part of a larger system.

Comment: Do you have physical access to the Ethernet plug of the unknown device?
Is so then all it takes is to connect any laptop with a gigabit card and check the windows reported connection speed , if is drops to 100Mbit then it's not a gigabit device

Comment: For the sake of the question and future users looking for the answer, let's pretend that it is a 10/100 device. In my case, I've actually discovered an off-the-shelf PoE injector inside of the device, so I'll look into its specifics.

Comment: For excluding the unused pairs you can get really inexpensive injectors/splitters and simply not connect a power supply. Example: 3 units at the bottom http://andahammer.com/poe/

Comment: @C.TowneSpringer If it is alternative B I would simply fashion a new ethernet cable end with those wires excluded from the end fitting.

Comment: I thought everything was supposed to have a pulse transformer on it so that adding PoE would never cause danger to downstream devices that don't expect it.

Comment: PoE won't give you full power unless the PD passes the "handshake" with the PSE. PoE PSE will not damage a non-PoE device.

Comment: @dextorb Can you provide a source of this claim?

Comment: @agweber http://www.microsemi.com/documents/powerdsine/whitepapers/PoE_and_IEEE802_3af.pdf Page 14. "In the beginning, only small voltage level is induced 
on the port's output, till a valid PD is detected during the Detection period" If the 25K resistor is not detected, then the PSE does not accept the device as a PoE PD.

Comment: Note that I am talking about PSEs and PDs that actually conform to the IEEE standards. If you're talking about some "DIY/hack" PoE then it's a crapshoot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this document helps [Introduction Basic principles of PoE Power over Ethernet](http://belden.picturepark.com/Website/?Action=viewPdf&AssetId=15240) (Page 4)

**Spare-pair power feed**

> Spare pair power feeds utilize wire pairs that are not otherwise used, the voltage being placed directly on the spare pairs 4/5 (+) and 7/8 (-). This method can be used only on networks with eight-wire cabling. This does not apply to Gigabit Ethernet, because here all eight wires are used for signal transmission and there are therefore no spares.

[image]

**Phantom power feed**

> A phantom power feed has the voltage coupled to wire pairs 1/2 ( ) and 3/6 (+). This method can be used for networks with four-wire or eight-wire cabling.

[image]

So you can check with a voltmeter, if there is a voltage in pins 4/5 - 7/8 then the method used is Spare-pair power feed.